# Struts 2 jquery plugin gride with ajax link

Tags: jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery

We are using Struts2 jQuery plugin to show the account summary as below

```
AccountNumber   Blance
87666           1,212$ 
31234           4,562$
12344           2,442$
```

User can click on account number to go to next page. The next account summary page should be loaded via Ajax.

The grid tag is:

```
<sjg:grid id="gridtable" dataType="json"
    href="%{url}" gridModel="gridModel" >
    <sjg:gridColumn name="accNo" title="AccountNo"
        formatter="linkBulider" />
    <sjg:gridColumn name="balance" title="Balance" />
```

The url must be an ajax call, so the `linkBuilder` can not simply return

```
 <a href="account-summary?id"=row.accNo>
```

To build a url we used a java script as below:

```
function linkBulider(cellvalue, options, row) {
    return "<a id=account"+row.accNo +" href=javascript:void(0)>" + cellvalue + "</a>";
}
```

This will make

```
<a id='account87666' href='javascript:void(0)'>87666</a>
<a id='account31234' href='javascript:void(0)'>31234</a>
<a id='account12344' href='javascript:void(0)'>12344</a>
```

Handling these links is the problem!
I write something like below but it will not work

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $.struts2_jquery.bind($("a[id^='account']"), {
        "jqueryaction" : "anchor",
        "targets" : "content",
        "href" : "/show-account-summary.action" //How should I pass the account number here?!
    });
});
```

My questions

- I don't know if the bind function works fine with more than one element?
- Also I don't know how to pass the account number to the action. (last line of JavaScript)
- I think this solution is strange, as my scenario is very straight forward, are there any better ways. May be some built in support which I missed.
- If I am on the correct rails, then please help me with the clicks function.

Comment: `struts2_jquery` is internal object, what a bind function are you talking?

Comment: I want to make a link so clicking on it makes an ajax call and opens the page in the defined target. This is way I used the struts2_jquery internal object. Do you think how should I make the link!

Comment: I think you should add a bounty to this question about 300 rep.

Comment: Is it because it is too hard or too tricky?! Any way 300 rep is all I have ;)

Comment: How much you need to work to post self-answer here?

Comment: I don't get what you mean? Right now I can answer my question!

Comment: Forget about `struts2_jquery` just use jQuery.

Comment: One hour passed where's your answer?

Comment: @RomanC I thought you mean I have the permission from stackoverflow, to answer my question! Well, I don't know the answer, but I will put it here as soon as I find a solution!

Comment: @AleksandrM As I am not very familary with jQuery, I thought using the strus2_jquery functions could be easier for me. I try to use direct jQuery to load dynamic data, some thing mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024403/jquery-ajax-load-post-result-to-div.

Comment: Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/on/ and http://api.jquery.com/load/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer...

First we need to add below property to grid tag `onGridCompleteTopics='addLinks'`

Then add the `addLinks` event subscribe and the new `linkBuilder` is as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    linkBulider = function(cellvalue, options, row) {
        return "<a class='accounts' account-num=" + row.accNo
                + " href=javascript:void(0)>" + cellvalue + "</a>";
    };
    $.subscribe('addLinks', function(event, data) {
        $(".accounts").click(function() {
            var acountNum = $("a.accounts").attr("account-num");
            if (acountNum != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    type : "Post",
                    url : "/account/account-summary.action",
                    data:{'accNo':acountNum},       
                    success : function(data) {
                         $('#content').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Please note if you do not add `onGridCompleteTopics` and try to bind the click on documents ready it won't work. Because in that way, the links are not ready and the `$(".accounts").click` will not apply to any links.

For the url, instead of hard coding the action you can use:

```
<s:url var="url"
    action="account-summary" namespace="account" />
```

And then in the java script:

```
url : "${url}"
```